# Send with PHP one million emails to one million users

Tags: php, email, smtp, send

For a project I'm building on my own, I'm looking for a technical solution to send one million emails (maybe 4 or 5 times with different call of actions) to one million users. I saw that in all the cases I'll have to pay and select a provider (SMTP) and pay by the number of mail I'll need to send. But I have few questions :

- Will the mail be sent from our server ?
- Is it technically possible to send 1 million email in < 24 hours ?
- This is something we can't do on our own without being blacklisted from email providers ?

Thanks in advance for your clarifications.

Comment: Who are you spamming...? Providers are likely to blacklist you unless you have explicit permission of those 1 million people.

Comment: You've come to the wrong place to learn how to spam.

Comment: It's not a spam. It will be a concept which will need that ammount of users. We will sell something to them and we will need their email to send what we are going to sell. People are going to give their email with their own agreement and freedom, and it will respect the EU legislation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Will the mail be sent from our server ?

Probably not, if u don't know how you can't send 1 million mails without being blacklisted

> 2. Is it technically possible to send 1 million email in < 24 hours ?

Sure, Facebook,  google and others huge website send more than 1 million mail everyday

> This is something we can't do on our own without being blacklisted from email providers ?

Nop if a lot of people tag your mail as spam you wil be blacklisted, so the only solution is.... dont send spam

If it's not for spam and you really need to send these mails maybe use something like mailchimp

Comment: It's not for SPAM but for call to actions linked to our concept. So it won't be SPAM for sure.
I saw that mailchimp and mailgun offer this kind of service, but will email be sent from their platform and will they be able to handle such an amount of emails to send ?

Comment: Yes every mail is sended by their servers, about the amount i never send more than 250k mails so i dont know, but they have special offers for high volume so i guess they can handle that.